# Pulling nbbo data from KDB server

Tags: kdb

I have a table of tickers with date, start time, end time for which i need to pull nbbo from the nbbo table on server. Eg

```
Date         starttime    endtime      sym
2014.05.01  15:10:38.000  15:10:58.000 KT
2014.05.01  15:15:53.000  15:16:23.000 IBM
2014.05.01  15:37:39.000  15:37:59.000 AAPL
```

Ideally, i will open a handle to the server and pull the data for each row by passing into this function:getnnbo and calling it as: `getnnbo[`KT;2014.05.01;15:10:38.000; 15:10:58.000]` where function is defined as

```
getnbbo:{[sym;dt;starttime;endtime]:h1"select 0.5*(first bid + first ask) from nbbo where date=",string[dt],",sym =`",string[sym], ",linetime within (",string[starttime],",",string[endtime],")"}
```

This function works when i call it as `getnnbo[`KT;2014.05.01;15:10:38.000; 15:10:58.000]` but i am not sure how to do it for each row in the table as i have to work with a handle to the server.

Comment: Hi, i tried this and it seems to work raze getnbbo ./:((`IBM;2014.05.01;15:15:53.000;15:16:23.000);(`AAPL;2014.05.01;15:37:39.00;15:37:59.000)). However, when i tried this on the table (lst: the table mentioned above) as raze getnbbo ./: lst, I am getting an error as wrong type, eg `a+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest instead of making request for each row on server, send full table (or part if it's huge) at once and fetch the data in one request from server. That should speed up the process because of less requests and server will also take less time in generating the result as  generally doing calculation on list is faster than individual row.

So your function should be something like below (just an example). You can optimize/modify it according to your need. I assume that your ticker table has one only entry for each  (date;sym) combination so that it can serve as primary key.

```
   getData:{[tbl] select 0.5*first[bid]+first[ask] from (nbbo ij `date`sym xkey tbl) where linetime within (st;et) }
```

Then run it on server using server handle. 'tbl' is your input table with tickers.

```
   handle(getData;tbl)
```

***Edit After ma3266 comment:***

I am assuming following two conditions:

a) nbbo table is partitioned on server

b) Your input tbl has date and symbol column names same as in nbbo. Otherwise you can use 'xcol' to rename them.

```
     getData:{tbl:0!tbl; tempNbbo:0!select from nbbo where date in tbl`date,sym in tbl`sym ; select 0.5*first[bid]+first[ask] from (tempNbbo ij `date`sym xkey tbl) where linetime within (starttime;endtime)}
```

But this can lead to heavy memory usage if your input table has data for many dates. In that case you can use following function which will break input table by date.

```
   getData:{tbl:0!`date xasc tbl; raze { tempNbbo:0!select from nbbo where date in x`date,sym in x`sym ; select 0.5*first[bid]+first[ask] from (tempNbbo ij `date`sym xkey x) where linetime within (starttime;endtime)} each (where differ tbl`date) cut tbl}
```

In both function, I am first removing primary key attribute from input table.

Also, check column types of nbbo and your input table. That might be giving you type error. This query is working fine for me.

Comment: Agreed, the operations should not be performed per-row, and the handle request should not be inside the function

Comment: Hi Rahul, i realized roe wise operation is really slow. I tried your method but i am getting an error (wrong type). I changed from ij to aj as ij requires exact match on keys. Have a look at the code below: getData:{[tbl] select sym,date,linetime,bid,ask from ( aj[`date`sym`linetime;tbl;nbbo])};
handle(getData;tbl)   where my tbl (date,sym,linetime are keys) is                                                  date                sym  linetime          shares
2014.05.01     KT    15:15:53.000  100
2014.05.01     KT    15:37:39.000  100
2014.05.01     KT    15:44:07.000  100

Comment: I am little confused here. In your initial post your table has starttime and endtime cols and not linetime(this is in nbbo I guess). For that 'aj' is not what you want  because that will give you only last row but i think you want all rows within start and end time. I have edited the answer considering your initial table as input (with start and end time cols.)

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks. I needed first bid and first ask from nbbo table as of startime (apologies i forgot to mention linetime is the startime). Hence, initially i thought i will pick first bid and first ask between starttime and endtime:linetime+30secs but when i saw your query passing the tbl to handle and performing an ij, i realize i can pass (sym date,starttime) to the handle and perform an asofjoin to get the bid and ask. The problem with ij is it will give bid&ask for only those rows which has an exact match and i needed the latest bid&ask after startime. I hope you got the problem

Comment: Understood, then your  'aj' command is correct but it will give you last quote before starttime not after.  Some points to check : a) Don't use nbbo directly in aj function if it is a partitioned table. You can use functions I mentioned in edited post and replace 'ij' command by 'aj'. b) Use proper attributes (`g# and `s#) for performance gain (they give tremendous gain on bulk data) mentioned on page http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/aj .

Comment: Hey Rahul, I am using the below code as provided by you and even 1000 obs are taking 5-10 of secs and one more thing: how is it different from pulling the nbbo table on to local host for the list of sym&date and do the aj join in the local environment  tbl:1000#distinct select date,sym,linetime from t

getData:{[tbl] tbl:0!`date xasc tbl; raze { tempNbbo:0!select from nbbo where date in x`date,sym in x`sym ; select date,sym,linetime,bid,ask from (aj[`date`sym`linetime;x;tempNbbo])} each (where differ tbl`date) cut tbl} res:handle(getData;tbl)

Comment: Try adding attributes on tempNbbo table :`g# on sym and `s# on time. That should speed up the process. You can fetch nbbo table from server on your local machine but that is not a good idea. Because nbbo(quotes) table normally has huge amount of data (even for a sym) and transferring that amount of data on network could result in bad performance .

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you, assuming `lst` is name of lookup table with `` `date`starttime`endtime`sym `` columns:

```
getnbbo ./: flip lst[`sym`date`starttime`endtime]
```

In the above we do the following:

- `` lst[`sym`date`starttime`endtime] `` - extract column values in the right order, so they align with function args
- `flip lst[...]` - transpose the column values, to them in the correct form for the function

---

Other general points regarding the code you've pasted --

#### Right-to-Left Evaluation

Taking the following from your select statement:

```
0.5*(first bid + first ask)
```

This is actually doing what you require, but by happenstance. It isn't actually scoped correctly. Kdb+ will evaluate this right-to-left. So in the above form it will

1. Get the first ask
2. Add the `bid` *column* to it
3. Take the first value from the result

This is calculating the value you want in this case, but will likely trip you over in a different scenario.

The correct way to write this is:

```
0.5 * first[bid] + first[ask]
```

This will ensure the order of evaluation is

1. Get the first `ask`
2. Get the first `bid`
3. Add the two
4. Multiply by 0.5

Alternatively, if you favour parenthesis, you could have written it as follows:

```
0.5 * (first bid)+(first ask)
```

#### Functions Over String Generation

The `getnbbo` function generates a query in string form - this is fine for simple cases, but generally not good practice. It's usually better to make this either (1) a function taking arguments or (2) switch to a functional select statement - (2) requires deeper understanding of Kdb+, I won't go into that here.

An immediate improvement would be to make it a function taking arguments. So `getnbbo` would become something along the lines of:

```
getnbbo:{[handle;sym;dt;starttime;endtime]
    getDataFunc:{[s;dt;st;et]
        select 0.5*first[bid]+first[ask] from nbbo where date=dt, sym=s, linetime within (st;et)
    };

    handle(getDataFunc;sym;dt;starttime;endtime)
 };
```

In the above,

- `getnbbo` func takes the same args as before, but we also pass in the handle (not required, but good practice)
- Within `getnbbo`, we define a new parameterised function `getDataFunc`, which given the parameters (args) returns the result of the select statement with appropriate clauses
- Finally, it sends the `getDataFunc` to the remote handle with the input args

Further Reading:

- [IPC - Message Formats](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Startingkdbplus/ipc#3.5_Message_Formats) - explains `handle(func;arg1;..;argN)`
- [Operations on Complex Column Data](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#872-operations-on-compound-column-data) - touches on Right to Left operation in queries

Comment: Thanks for the Reply MdSalih. The function works properly and thanks for suggesting a great way to pass a local copy of the function on to a server. Sadly, one thing which i wanted to avoid is to pull the nbbo table (for 3 months and 500 tickers and then do aj) but this way of passing each row from "lst" table makes it really slow..Anyways, thanks for the help..Really appreciate it..Also, can you please suggest me some good book on Q programming?